# Ошибка при сборке проекта Unresolved reference: DaggerAppComponent

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger2

Я потаюсь изучить Dagger 2, который в теории кажется не таким сложным, но на практике я уже провел 2 дня чтобы запустить проект, но безрезультатно.

```
@Module
class ActivityModule {

    @Provides
    @NonNull
    @Singleton
    fun getActivitys() : TestClass = TestClass()
}

@Module
class AppModule(val context: Context) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun getContexts() : Context = context
}

@Component(modules = [(ActivityModule::class), (AppModule::class)])
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

**App**

```
class App : Application() {

    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        appComponent = buildComponent()
    }

    fun getComponent() : AppComponent = appComponent

    private fun buildComponent(): AppComponent {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(AppModule(this))
                .activityBindgsModule(ActivityModule())
                .build()
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var testClass: TestClass

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        App().getComponent().inject(this)

        Log.d("MAIN", testClass.getString())
    }
}
```

В манифесте прописал

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
...
```

В Build зависимости прописал такие, пробовал обновлять, не помогает.

```
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11"
```

При запусти проекта на эмулятор, во время сборки я получаю ошибку в разделе Messanger

```
Error:(25, 17) Unresolved reference: DaggerAppComponent
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

А вот если я скачать готовый пример с GitHub [Ссылка на это проект](https://github.com/mladenrakonjac/Mvp-With-Dagger-2.11) всё компилируется, но стоит мне начать новый проект, я получаю ошибки. Данный пример я писал сделаю другой статьи.

**Обновил**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.android_developer_community.dagerss"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.14"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.14"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.14"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.14"
}
```

Comment: Это и есть причина почему Kotlin не взлетит и почему не взлетают все JVM based языки: groovy, scala, ceylon и имя им легион

Comment: попробуйте `rebuild` проекта сделать.

Comment: @Barmaley, не думаю, что дело тут в Kotlin) Скорее всего где-то что-то пропущено в коде и, если на Java переписать будет тоже самое выдавать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я скопировал в чистый проект код из github на java. проект собрался, но с ошибкой уже на эмуляторе. Потом я преобразовал с помощью плагина java в kotlin получил ошибку. Наверное котлин что-то не правильно сгенерировал.

Comment: @CegreiUlanov, кажется у вас вот этого не хватает в скрипте сборки: `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, да, не было.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых:

```
App().getComponent().inject(this)
```

создаст новый экземпляр класса `App`, а Вам необходимо получить уже существующий. Делается это так:

```
(applicationContext as App)
```

В Вашем случае итоговая строка будет выглядеть так:

```
(applicationContext as App).getComponent().inject(this)
```

---

Ну и во-вторых:

Как Вы могли понять, ошибка указывает на то, что `DaggerAppComponent` не известен как класс, а значит не импортирован.
Можно попробовать прописать импорт самому, нужно указать пакет, в котором у Вас лежит `AppComponent`, только добавить к названию класса слово "Dagger" (этот класс у вас сгенерируется в процессе компиляции)

**UPD:**

Необходимо добавить `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` в начало файла. Также необходимо добавить

```
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

в `android` для того чтобы котлин генерировал "заглушки"

Comment: Я прописал то что вы привели в примере, и проследовал вашей рекомендации, но ошибка прежняя выскакивает.

Comment: @CegreiUlanov модули и компонент у Вас располагаются в отдельных файлах?

Comment: Но теперь он еще на пакет ругается, с той же ошибкой и тем именем.

Comment: В этот раз все модули и компоненты у меня расположены в папки di

Comment: `import info.android_developer_community.dagerss.di.ActivityModule
import info.android_developer_community.dagerss.di.AppComponent
import info.android_developer_community.dagerss.di.AppModule
import info.android_developer_community.dagerss.di.DaggerAppComponent`

Comment: У меня два разных проекта, те же зависимости в builde, но с разной структурой и подходом которые я брал с разных примеров. Возможно я где-то что-то упустил, т.к проект скаченный компилируется, а когда я создаю чистый и пишу сам, нет...

Comment: @CegreiUlanov Покажите, пожалуйста, статью, по которой Вы писали

Comment: [вот](https://android.jlelse.eu/dagger-2-part-i-basic-principles-graph-dependencies-scopes-3dfd032ccd82)

Comment: Возможно это из-за kotlina, я попробую другие примеры уже на котлине, потом расскажу.

Comment: @CegreiUlanov а можно полностью Ваш `gradle`-скрипт увидеть?

Comment: обновил вопрос, посмотрите.

Comment: @CegreiUlanov обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, от этой ошибки я избавился. Правда другие появились, но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: создал новый проект, добавил всё выше перечисленные ваши рекомендации, и все заработала без единой ошибки. Еще раз спасибо.